# Jupyter update custom extensions when modifying YAML file

Tags: jupyter-extensions

I'm working on an extension for Jupyter (not JupyterLab), and I'm having issues refreshing its YAML file. When I modify it (for example, adding a parameter), I update the extension with `jupyter nbextension enable test/main`, but after that, `Jupyter.notebook.config.data` doesn't show the new parameter I've added in the YAML file.

What do I do wrong?

Here's a complete example:
config.yaml:

```
Type: Jupyter Notebook Extension
Compatibility: 4.x, 5.x
Name: Test extension
Main: main.js
Link: README.md
Parameters:
- name: test.my_int
  description: My int
  input_type: number
  min: 0
  step: 50
  default: 250
```

main.js

```
define([
    'base/js/namespace'
], function(Jupyter) {
    "use strict";
    
    // defaults, overridden by server's config
    var options = {
        my_int: 250
    };
    
    function load_jupyter_extension() {
        Jupyter.notebook.config.loaded.then(function on_config_loaded () {
            console.log(Jupyter.notebook.config.data.test.my_int)
            $.extend(options, Jupyter.notebook.config.data.test);
        }, function on_config_load_error (reason) {
            console.warn('Using defaults after error loading config:', reason);
        })
    }

    return {
        load_jupyter_extension : load_jupyter_extension,
        load_ipython_extension : load_jupyter_extension,
    };
});
```

opening a Notebook displays this error in the console:

Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Jupyter.notebook.config.data.test is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by deleting C:\Users\XXX\.jupyter\nbconfig\notebook.json which, for some reason, didn't refresh. restarting Jupyter after that regenerated it. I don't know why this happened, nor if it will happen again. If anyone has an idea about that...